# PHP download script replaced every instance of 0D0A with 0A in text file

Tags: php, text, ftp, ftp-client

OK, the title says it all. I use the following PHP script to download a text file from the server. After the download, all instances of 0D0A (\r\n) have been replaced with 0A (\n). Is there a way to fix this problem.
Thanks.

```
<?php

$file = "./some_file.txt";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);

?>
```

Comment: It might have something to do with the content encoding.  Maybe you can set it to UTF8 or something

Comment: I tried adding header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); to the code but that didn't do anything.

Comment: why text file transfer using binary encoding???

Comment: why? Is there a problem with that? Have any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the transfer encoding line and change the type to text/plain

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't work. I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Upon more research, I realized that the problem wasn't with the script. The script downloaded the file exactly as it was on the server. It was the FTP client that was converting the text file to make it compatible with Windows (which uses \r\n for line breaks instead \n).